# Swaks (Swiss Army Knife for SMTP) can send, but Spring Java cannot send mail

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, ubuntu-server

I am developing a service in Spring and I can send email when I am running this same app from my development machine, but when I deploy it to a server it does not work.
I checked from the server with Swaks and it also works from command line but it's not working from Spring.
Here is the Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="my-domain.tld"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="username" value="myemail@my-domain.tld"/>
    <property name="password" value="mypassword"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It stops after this line(from log file)

```
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

Here is the code to send email

```
@Component
public class EmailProvider {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Async
public void sendEmail(final String to, final String subject, final String body, final String cc, final String bcc, final boolean html) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(to) || StringUtils.isEmpty(subject) || StringUtils.isEmpty(body)) {
        return;
    }

    MimeMessagePreparator message = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

        @Override
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mmsg) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper mm = new MimeMessageHelper(mmsg);
            mm.setTo(new InternetAddress(to));
            mm.setSubject(subject);
            mm.setFrom("from@my-domain.tld");
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cc)) {
                mm.setCc(cc);
            }
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(bcc)) {
                mm.setBcc(bcc);
            }
            mm.setText(body, html);
        }
    };
    mailSender.send(message);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what is happening, are you getting an error. Post the logs.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. And you can see the method is sending in background(async). It just stop doing another SMTP `HELO` after initial one and start authentication.

Comment: It does not matter I use async or not. I already said it is working from my development machine but from real server.

Comment: Try setting some of the debugging properties described in [SSLNOTES.txt](https://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt).  It looks like you're getting stuck accessing the keystore/truststore or dealing with certificates.